# Vuex syntax error with localcomputed function in combination with getter and setter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I get syntax error when combining Vuex localcomputed object with get/set together with store mappings.

As seen in the Vuex docs you can map your store methods like this with the object spread operater like:

```
computed: {
  localComputed () { /* ... */ },
  // mix this into the outer object with the object spread operator
  ...mapState({
    // ...
  })
}
```

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html##object-spread-operator

Also you can create computed setters like:

```
computed: {
  fullName: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      var names = newValue.split(' ')
      this.firstName = names[0]
      this.lastName = names[names.length - 1]
    }
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

I can create either a computed object with get set or have mapState/mapGetters etc. - but not in combination. It break the syntax  (error is: expected function name after the function declarations).

```
    computed: {
        localComputed () {
            localMethod: {
                get: function () {
                        // retrieve
                },
                set: function (newContent) {
                    // set
                }
            }
        }, ...mapState([
                           
                       ]), ...mapGetters([])

    }
```

How do i combine these two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to define **localMethod** inside **localComputed**.

In the docs, **localComputed** is just an example name for a computed property in your component. You don't have to put all of your other local computed properties within it.

Therefore, you should be able to do the following:

```
computed: {

  localComputed: {
    get: function () {
      // retrieve
    },
    set: function (newContent) {
      // set
    }
  },

  anotherLocalComputed: {
    get: function () {
      // retrieve
    },
    set: function (newContent) {
      // set
    }
  },

  ...mapState([]),

  ...mapGetters([])

}
```

Comment: I'm trying this and still getting `SyntaxError, Unexpected token mapState(['myStateVar'])`. Without mapstate mixin it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample. I have been using this approach for more than a year

```
// in some utils/vuex.js file 
export const mapSetter = (state, setters = {}) => (
  Object.keys(state).reduce((acc, stateName) => {
    acc[stateName] = {
      get: state[stateName],
   };
   // check if setter exists
   if (setters[stateName]) {
      acc[stateName].set = setters[stateName];
   }

   return acc;
 }, {})
);
```

In your component.vue file

```
  import { mapSetter  } from 'path/to/utils/vuex.js';
  ...

  export default {
    name: 'ComponentName',
    computed: {
      ...mapSetter(
        mapState({
          result: ({ ITEMS }) => ITEMS.result,
          total: ({ ITEMS }) => ITEMS.total,
          current: ({ ITEMS }) => ITEMS.page,
          limit: ({ ITEMS }) => ITEMS.limit,
        }),
        {
          limit(payload) {
            this.$store.dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LIMIT, payload });
          },
        },
      )
    },
  }
```

now v-model binding should work.